Rand() creating duplicates when I assign random values to a matrix
I have a class that creates circles of two different types, red and green. I stored this in a x-by-2 matrix where 2x is the number of circles I want. I'm trying to assign random X and Y values to each circle.
When I run this program, almost every red and green circle stack together on the same coordinate. Why is this happening? It wasn't when I didn't have a matrix.
Here is the part of my code that does this
Particle Green[10][2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Greencount/2; j++) {
        std::cout << Green[i][j].X << ", " << Green[i][j].Y << std::endl;
        if (i == 0) {
            Green[i][j].color = sf::Color(0, 255, 0);
        }
        else if (i == 1) {
            Green[i][j].color = sf::Color(255, 0, 0);
        }
        std::cout << i << ", " << j << std::endl;
        Green[i][j].init(memory);

Green[i][j].init(memory) assigns a random coordinate value to the object using this code
float X = rand() % WinX, Y = rand() % WinY;

And then draws the particles to the screen.
Here is the output of the X and Y coordinates of each point with the matrix coordinate below it:
41, 467
0, 0
334, 500
0, 1
169, 724
0, 2
478, 358
0, 3
962, 464
0, 4
705, 145
0, 5
281, 827
0, 6
961, 491
0, 7
995, 942
0, 8
827, 436
0, 9
169, 724
1, 0
478, 358
1, 1
962, 464
1, 2
705, 145
1, 3
281, 827
1, 4
961, 491
1, 5
995, 942
1, 6
827, 436
1, 7
391, 604
1, 8
902, 153
1, 9


The Random dose not guarantee that it will be unique you can seed it with time or I an J
To ensure unique positions for your particles:
Check for Duplicates: Maintain a list of assigned coordinates. Before assigning a new position, verify it’s not already in use. If it is, generate new coordinates until a unique one is found.
Grid System: Use the loop indices (e.g., i and j) to calculate unique positions. Offset each particle's position by a fixed distance based on these indices, ensuring they are distinctly placed while allowing for some randomness.

Library functions rand() and srand() are a legacy component, and on some platforms, statistical properties of their implementations were (far) less than satisfactory. Did you try with the modern C++ random number generation facilities, as described for example in the N3551 White paper ?

You print Green[i][j].X and Green[i][j].Y before you call Green[i][j].init, where X and Y are allegedly initialized. In addition, float X = rand() % WinX, Y = rand() % WinY; defines two local variables named X and Y - it doesn't assign to data members named X and Y. I strongly suspect your actual code doesn't do what you claim it does. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].
